# How do I add elements of a set and print their sum?

Tags: python-3.x, set

how do i add elements of the set and print their sum

i have done it by converting the set into list is their any other way without converting the set into a list

```
a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
x = 0
sum = 0
while x != 10:
    z = list(a1)[x]
    sum += z
    x += 1
    print(sum)


a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
x = 0
sum = 0
while x != 10:
    z = a1[x]
    sum += z
    x += 1
    print(sum)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Usman/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/ddd.py", line
>   5, in 
>       z=(a1[x]) TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

I expect the result to be 55

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sum` function.

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
print(sum(a))
```

Comment: Why don't you check [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) out?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = set(range(1, 10+1)) # a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
>>> sum(a)
55
>>>
```

`set` iterables *are unordered*, and therefore *have no index*. That explains the `TypeError` you are getting.

Comment: Why not 11 instead if 10 + 1?

Comment: It's just my habit of putting `10+1` so I remember that the `range` ends at 10.

Comment: What's a function operator?

Comment: You mean call operator?

Comment: Can you link the relevant part?

Comment: I meant argument, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `sum` is great for this as per the other answers. Without using `sum`however, OP was probably trying to use a constructiom like these, that might be useful in contexts that require other actions, not only `sum`. so I am also posting it here:

```
>>> sum = 0
>>> for item in a1:
...     sum += item
... 
>>> print(sum)
55
>>>
```